# How can I run a shell script from bashrc file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

What I basically want to achieve is to type in a custom command in the terminal and a specific shell script should run each time.

I could achieve the above requirement with folders,by modifying the bashrc file like below

```
alias myScripts="cd /home/arun/Desktop/scripts"
```

Now when I try to do the same with a bash script by modiying the bashrc file as given below,

```
alias masterScript="bash /home/arun/Desktop/scripts/myMasterScript.sh"
```

now when I type masterScript im getting the following error:

```
"bash : No such file or directory" error
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: I think i may have an answer but let me make sure I have this correct .. when you ... alias myScripts in bashrc it will open the folder path but if you alias it to a script it says no file... is this right?

Comment: I do not understand why this would be preferable to just put your script in your $PATH. If you move your script to ~/bin and add ~/bin to your path variable you can execute it from everywhere.

Comment: Or if you don't want to change `$PATH` linking the script into a directory that is already in `$PATH`, i.e. `ln -s /home/arun/Desktop/scripts/myMasterScript.sh /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Sounds like the problem is/was that `/home/arun/Desktop/scripts/myMasterScript.sh` just didn't exist - typo?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a function:

```
function masterScript()
{
    if [ -e /home/arun/Desktop/scripts/myMasterScript.sh ]
    then
        bash /home/arun/Desktop/scripts/myMasterScript.sh
    fi
}
```

And make sure your script is executable:

```
chmod 755 /home/arun/Desktop/scripts/myMasterScript.sh
```

Comment: That's the way i would do it. +1 . There's no need for script , if you can achieve same action in few lines of code. Functions are ideal for that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out .. I simply made it

```
alias masterScript="cd /home/arun/Desktop/scripts && myMasterScript.sh"
```

Comment: sorry you are correct .. i updated my answer .. missed the ending quote :(

Comment: a bash terminal will display a newline & `>` waiting to close an open quote, makes it easy to catch. anyway, i'll del my old comment, and maybe this one tomorrow. +1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `masterScript.sh` is executable by doing:

```
chmod +x masterScript.sh
```

If the script is not executable, the bash command cannot run it and you'll get these kind of error messages.

Comment: This is not true - try it with `bash non-executable-file` and bash will run it

Comment: Ah right.. the `+x` permission seems to only matter if run via `./masterScript.sh`